# Upper and lower case business names and SEO

Tags: seo, name, business, case-sensitive

I've been using lower case to describe my business name, in my content and titles, and in business directories.

So much so that when Google contacts me I notice it is always referring to my business name in this way, and it also appears in searches as 'businessname'.

> businessname Web Design

So my question is, would it be detrimental now for me to change my tact and start using:

> Businessname Web Design

Comment: Makes no difference.

Answer (score 3):

Not only can you refer to your *business* as *Business* with no effect, but if you have a domain *thisismybusiness.com* it is fine to use *ThisIsMyBusiness.com* or for emails, *YourName@ThisIsMyBusiness.com* - this is known as camel case and as you can see, is much easier to read.

Capitalisation will not be detrimental to Google or other listings.

However be warned that *thisismybusiness.com/myfile.php* is *not* the same as *thisismybusiness.com/MyFile.php* - file names and directories are case sensitive on most servers, and even if not, it is better practice to treat them as though they are.

Comment: I do not use upper case in URL's, it's more to do with how our business appears in searches and how Google interacts with our business because I have been using 'businessname Web Design' for so long

Comment: That's fine and neither will be detrimental.  My answer should have reflected that, it does now.